# Hello . here i am working with a stepper motor and i need to know how to convert rpm to rps

Tags: rpm, stepper

To specify more i need the stepper motor to control a rod for a linear movements with a speed of 1mmpersec .
Can anyone here help me please

Answer (score 0):

RPM divided by 60 will give you RPS